# Implement Stack with incompatible type

Tags: java

I was trying to implement the stack and somehow when I try to run the code, the compiler say it was "incompatible type". Please help

```
class MyArrayStack<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Stack<E> {
   int key,data,size = 0; 
   int[] array = new int[12];
   int element;

   public void push(E e) {
      data = (int) e;
      array[size] = data;
      size++;
      System.out.println("The Element is inserted Successfully");
   }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned below Stack is not an interface. when you mean implement a stack, do you mean create a custom stack ? If yes then you would not need to extend or implement any class or interface

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Stack is a class, not an interface. You can remove the ArrayList

```
import java.util.Stack;

class MyArrayStack<E> extends Stack<E> {

    int key, data, size = 0;

    int[] array = new int[12];

    int element;

    public E push(E e) {

        data = (int) e;
        array[size] = data;
        size++;
        System.out.println("The Element is inserted Successfully");

        return e;
    }
}
```